# Should I choose industry internship or research assistant job at the lab?

Tags: phd, computer-science, professorship, international-students, internship

Currently, I'm a CS master student and I want to apply for a PhD program in the coming Fall. I'm interested in the system research (i.e., distributed system).

Right now, I have two opportunities presented in front of me:

1. Go to a professor's research lab over the summer. The professor's interest is in distributed storage and that quite matches with my interest.

   - Pros: Work with a professor directly
   - Cons: there isn't much pay and I want to rely on myself financially instead of family.
2. Do a software internship with High-Performance Computing (HPC) Infrastructure.

   - Pros: Good pay and industry experience that relates to my interest (HPC infrastructure is related to general distributed system (Dynamo, Spanner) but not quite the same). I also heard system research values industry experience more but not sure this is true (internship is from a big company but not in Tech industry)
   - Cons: is not research experience

To make thing complicated, I have contacted the professor before I got the internship offer and I don't know if I should talk my situation with the Professor. In addition, I'm an international student and if I couldn't get to a good PhD program, I may want to go to industry directly but I'm not sure if an experience in a research lab helps.

**Questions:**

1. Which one should I choose?
2. Should I talk to the professor about my situation?
3. Does systems research value industry experience (more than other fields)?

PS: Thanks for the editing the format and input from comments

Comment: We can't tell you what you should do. Perhaps focus your question on facts you are unsure of that we could help clarify. One might be: does systems research value industry experience (more than other fields)?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I add your comment into the question :)

Comment: If you want to stay in Academia, get an internship in research lab. If you want to have a high pay job in industry after you get the masters degree, take the internship with an HPC. Simple as that. Would you please explain why do you have this question?

Comment: I'm interested in the distributed system but it's really hard for me to come up with good intuition and research problems about the system without actually see some production system in real life. Maybe I can achieve the same by reading papers? Also, I think some work experience in the US can help me to get a job if I didn't get a good PhD program (working with the advisor I want to work with). @scaaahu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the people involved. If I were your professor, I would appreciate it if you would explain the situation and ask for advice.

Of course, I would not give you any advice ;-), but I would ask you some questions which might help you finding a good decision - and maybe this is a hidden job interview.

Comment: May I ask what questions are :)

Comment: Hard to tell - it depends really on the flow of conversation. I would try to figure out what's best for you, which skills you are lacking, your financial situation, your research interest, your future career plans, ... It's more a coaching...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Actually, I talked with my professor and we had a pleasant email conversation.

Comment: good to hear! Did you come to a decision, yet? All the best!

Comment: Yes. Industry experience is actually equally important with research experience.  My professor suggests me to take the internship and find time to do research in the fall semester with some remote collaboration.